# TypeScript runtime error: module_1.Class is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, typescript, class

I've built a library called luna-pluto, it's a TypeScript library and published it to a private nexus repository, from the main app I imported the library like below

```
import { ServiceConfiguration } from 'luna-pluto';
```

I'm trying to instantiate the class ServiceConfiguration like

```
private _serviceConfiguration: any;
this._serviceConfiguration = new ServiceConfiguration();
```

When debugging or when trying to run the application it's throwing the following error:

```
Error: luna_pluto_1.ServiceConfiguration is not a constructor
```

here is my class ServiceConfiguration.ts

```
export class ServiceConfiguration {
        public req: HttpRequests;
        public configuration: IConfig;
        public packageInfo = new PackageJSON();

        public async applyConfig(configuration: IConfig) {
            this.configuration = configuration;
            await this.applyRequestConfig();
        }

        private async applyRequestConfig(): Promise<any> {
            const factory = new HttpFactory();
            const httpConfig = this.configuration.get('api') as HttpOptions;
            this.req = await factory.getProvider(httpConfig);
        }

}
```

my index.js

```
"use strict";
exports.ServiceConfiguration = require("./lib/ServiceConfiguration");
exports.NullHttpRequests = require("./lib/persistence/http/NullHttpRequests");
```

my index.d.ts

```
export class ServiceConfiguration {
        configuration: IConfig;
        packageInfo: PackageJSON;
        requests: HttpRequests;
        applyConfig(configuration: IConfig): Promise<any>;
}
```

both are using TypeScript 3.4.1, and when I move the mini library into the same .ts file it works perfectly fine and returns the expected data. I believe the code on the library is fine.

P.S. tried to import the library in adifferent way and still not working. e.g.

```
const ServiceConfiguration = require("luna-pluto");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in ‘index.ts’ you need to ‘export * from “./ServiceConfiguration”’
Your current export looks more like type export for me.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, can you please elaborate? or give a short example please

Comment: also sorry my bad, that's my index.d.ts, I already fixed my typo